# How to generalized formula to move x steps in a circle?

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

As we know if we have an array of size n, let's say a0, a1, a2, ......, an-1. we can preform **x** move clockwise with **((ai + x) % n)** and anticlockwise with **((ai — x) % n + n) % n.**

Can we generalized for clockwise and anticlockwise for the index **i to j** *(0 <= i, j < n)*?

So what will be the formula if we want to move **x** (*x can be greater than (j - i + 1)*) steps in a circle from **ai to aj** *(0 <= i, j < n)* in an array(*0 indexed and size of the array is n*)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean just move from ai _towards_ aj? I.e. it can end in not aj? If so, can't you just put an if statement, depending on the direction?

Comment: @Cihan I need a formula for both clockwise and anticlockwise

Comment: You want to know how many steps of x are required to move from ai to aj? And whether it is possible or not?